# RequestContext returns 404 error for my imagaes?

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, requestcontext

I stumbled on a silly situation with Django's RequestContext thing. Here is my question:

I stored all my images in my media/uploads file. In my template I'm simply using :

```
{% for photo in photos %}
  <a href="#"> <img src="{{gallery_root}}/{{photo.get_name}}" /></a>
{% endfor %}
```

My view is :

```
def gallery_view(request):
    photos = Photo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('gallery/sampleGallery.html',{'photos':photos},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my settings file :

```
GALLERY_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "media/uploads")
```

And i have a contextprocessor file which contains:

```
from django.conf import settings

def gallery_root(request):
    return {'gallery_root':settings.GALLERY_ROOT}
```

When I open my template, the image's path appears however the server gives 404, the path seems correct but django can not serves them.. So what's the reason that I can not see images on my template ?

The image source appears like this :

```
<a href="#"> <img src="/Users/imperium/Desktop/sample/media/uploads/popo.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there, it's probably that your media isn't being served propery.
Try something like this in your urls.py file.

```
# if we're in DEBUG mode, allow django to serve media
# This is considered inefficient and isn't secure.
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.GALLERY_ROOT}),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`MEDIA_ROOT` is the filesystem path to your media, not the URL path. Building on the suggestion from mongoose_za, your template should look like:

```
{% for photo in photos %}
  <a href="#"> <img src="/media/{{photo.get_name}}" /></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, you can define a new constant in `settings.py` which corresponds to the URL root you've chosen, and use this both in `urls.py` as well as in your templates.